# Arduino Classifying EMG signal by ANN

Tags: arduino, neural-network

Currently I'm trying to replicate this wonderful project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8pwmzUVx48, though with more minimum hardware, in which for the classification i'm using a neural network embbeded inside the arduino uno which had been trained offline in more stronger PC. The code of the classifier is here

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <Wire.h>

double dataMagnitude[100];
double feature[7];
double feat_hid[10];
double output[4];
int classi;

const double w_hid[8][10] =
{
    {18.9336670380822,11.9186055569093,-5.40114594311576,-21.1410711100689,-49.7798510124792,-14.8215222433047,-34.7308138535581,118.348601654702,-13.6275407707706,-11.6090487951753},
    {-21.4994463865001,72.0672467700052,4.05328299052883,21.4875491464005,51.1604296852446,-15.8459578543758,6.30350750703905,-152.565733734759,12.8648040583067,13.8199895673734},
    {8.66214515599865,-200.488705071393,-5.86973559011113,-23.4805286444925,-1.11016147795671,-3.04686605995311,-93.4143749063794,-73.8925691072615,-6.18427236042285,-10.9872535411407},
    {-12.317892447947,-37.2154526807162,3.83978412266769,2.12866508710205,-11.9740446238331,10.2198116665101,41.9369083083022,63.2036147993661,1.40768362243561,15.4978881385563},
    {7.58319670243546,161.895072542918,-2.3654701067923,1.91708846557259,-2.87224127392426,-16.5850302581614,45.2372430254377,34.255971511768,-2.30234070310014,-7.8952356779332},
    {0.603971580989218,128.0244079393,0.628535912033608,-1.25788426737745,-0.204480047424961,-41.3372322514891,3.26860448943873,4.163893213914,0.443532051478394,-0.276136697942473},
    {-3.63944154925129,18.3802540188974,0.975095285922393,-0.326187652485656,1.25521855841132,39.4877166809573,-15.3542772116519,-14.9546824078715,0.965532742621277,3.72386985716534},
    {5.93321854314305,12.673690719929,-3.36580252980446,-21.2089241183081,-10.8980644878121,-7.29095431091201,-30.2240843969778,-2.48980394834853,-5.4167647620581,-5.68671825319015}
}, w_out[11][4] =
{
    {1.07887052819228,-21.9615926704441,105.450147012522,-84.5674248703326},
    {0.0344508533215184,0.551350792323934,-0.96380329372866,0.37800164808339},
    {-99.251397621058,23.1671754381478,7.53147169676884,68.5527504861813},
    {-5.0354869957171,4.36918523413481,0.408725687040089,0.257576074543764},
    {-27.4478368365984,7.00659524306471,1.74370945871769,18.6975321348269},
    {-0.213736004615516,-0.784795805217531,0.0732416484342244,0.925290161399087},
    {8.62052547929066,-45.9408034639393,116.959261953552,-79.6389839689755},
    {-8.5317661802465,45.4251911929737,-117.146523754862,80.2530987422069},
    {127.053878005091,-29.4397580015468,-9.33919798608733,-88.2749220175082},
    {1.11869995358251,-21.5111648695486,105.002356379838,-84.6098914639344},
    {-5.81786935588552,3.78305066207264,0.11556429335063,-0.0807455995360207}
};

double S, Sig, Sigma, Sigma1, Sigma2, MAV, RMS, VAR, SDT, WL, ZC, SSC, Xn, accum, accumi;
char analogpin = 0, N=100;

void setup()
{
    /* add setup code here */
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  do{
    //data acqusition
    for( int i = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
       Xn = (analogRead(analogpin))-510;
      dataMagnitude[i]=Xn;
      delayMicroseconds(830);
  //    Serial.println(dataMagnitude[i]);
    }

    S = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        S = S + dataMagnitude[i];
    }
    Sig = 0;
    Sigma = 0;
    Sigma1 = 0;
    Sigma2 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Sig = Sig + abs(dataMagnitude[i]);
        Sigma = Sigma + pow(dataMagnitude[i], 2);
        Sigma1 = Sigma1 + pow((dataMagnitude[i] - S / N), 2);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        Sigma2 = Sigma2 + abs(dataMagnitude[i + 1] - dataMagnitude[i]);
    }

    //featureextract
    MAV = (((1 / (double)N)*Sig-27.67)*2/(272.02-27.67))-1;

    RMS = (sqrt((1 / (double)N)*Sigma)-34.91002721)*2/(284.1419012-34.91002721)-1;

    VAR = (((1 / (double)(N))*Sigma1)-698.4139)*2/(52178.5691-698.4139)-1;

    SDT = (sqrt((1 / (double)(N)) * Sigma1)-26.42752164)*2/(228.4262881-26.42752164)-1;

    WL = (Sigma2-1621)*2/(11273-1621)-1;

    //ZC = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        if (dataMagnitude[i] == 0 && dataMagnitude[i] != dataMagnitude[i + 1])
        {
            ZC++;
        }
    }
    ZC = (ZC-0)*2/(39-0)-1;

    //SSC = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N - 2; i++)
    {
        if (dataMagnitude[i]>dataMagnitude[i + 1] && dataMagnitude[i + 1]<dataMagnitude[i + 2])
        {
            SSC++;
        }
        else if (dataMagnitude[i]<dataMagnitude[i + 1] && dataMagnitude[i + 1]>dataMagnitude[i + 2])
        {
            SSC++;
        }
    }
    SSC = (SSC-48)*2/(78-48)-1;

    double feature[] = { MAV, RMS, VAR, SDT, WL, ZC, SSC };

    //neural network construction
    //first-hidden layer
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      accum = w_hid[7][i];
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
      {
        accum += (feature[j] * w_hid[j][i]);
      }
      feat_hid[i] = tanh(accum);
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            accumi = w_out[10][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                accumi += (feat_hid[j] * w_out[j][i]);
            }
            output[i] = round(accumi);
        }

        //Classify the output
        if (output[0] == 1 && output[1] < 1 && output[2] < 1 && output[3] < 1)
        {
            classi = 1;
        }
        else if (output[0] < 1 && output[1] == 1 && output[2] < 1 && output[3] < 1)
        {
            classi = 2;
        }
        else if (output[0] < 1 && output[1] < 1 && output[2] == 1 && output[3] < 1)
        {
            classi = 3;
        }
        else if (output[0] < 1 && output[1] < 1 && output[2] < 1 && output[3] == 1)
        {
            classi = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            classi = 0;
        }


Wire.beginTransmission(5);
Wire.write(classi);
//Wire.write(int(output[2]));
Wire.endTransmission();
Serial.println("wew");
Serial.println(output[0]);
Serial.println(output[1]);
Serial.println(output[2]);
Serial.println(output[3]);
//Serial.println(classi);

//Serial.println(feature[1]);
//Serial.println(feature[2]);
//Serial.println(feature[3]);
//Serial.println(feature[4]);
//Serial.println(feature[5]);
//Serial.println(feature[6]);


        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            feat_hid[i] = 0;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            output[i] = 0;
        }
  }while(analogRead(analogpin)>0);
}
```

But the real time implementation is rather dissatisfying, in which the output always mismatched, though by offline implementation is quite better.

My assumption is that the data capturing when online is rather bad, or maybe because any other things?

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

How did you train the network offline?
If you have used Matlab to train the network (i.e. to identify the weight and bias values) and then implement the same network on Arduino.
In such case we have problems with number precision. Matlab by default works on 64 bit precision whereas Arduino works on 32 bit.
Difference in the way the numbers are represented creates the Error.